# Blocks of non-contradicting n-tupels

Tags: python, numpy, null, sparse-matrix, columnsorting

I would like to efficiently compute a boolean matrix that stores all non-contradicting pairings over a large set of n-tupels with possible empty fields, for example:

```
(1,None,44,22,44,None,33,)

(1,24,None,None,None,23,33,)
```

These two tupels do **not** contradict each other.

Ultimately, I am looking for *python* code, but this is more about the general idea and I have a feeling there should be some matrix operations that enable this - or a simple tree structure. The tricky part is that an empty value `None` is not contradicting any given value.

Comment: What is sparse about this?  Just that you expect few `True` elements?  It might be good if you gave a more complete example.

Comment: @hpaulj That is what I meant, but I removed that detail as it is not important and might not even hold true.

Comment: It may be obvious but could you define what you mean by _non-contradicting pairings_?

Comment: element wise comparison, either both equal or at least one of the two is None